# UIMA Ruta Check Feature of sub Annotation

Tags: uima, ruta

Is it possible to make a rule to match the value of a FEATURE in an annotation that is a child of another Annotation?

Example:

Annotation Person
   Annotation Doctor
             Feature TYPE: xyz

something like Person.Doctor{FEATURE("TYPE","xyz")}

Also is it possible to create a rule that matches a FEATURE in an annotation that is PARTOF another annotation?

|-----------A1------------|

|-----A2-----|    |---A3----|

Make a rule where

A3{FEATURE("X","1")} but also A3{PARTOF(A1)}

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `is a child of another Annotation`? It's covered or its a sub-type? Can you extend the description of your example a bit?

Comment: You should not use `type` as the name of a feature.

Comment: "It's covered or its a sub-type" both!!!

First part of the question is to how to check the feature of a subtype.

Second part of the question to check if an annotation covers another annotation that has a certain feature.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: TYPE was a bad example. Any FEATURE!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a type `Doctor` and its parent type called `Person` which defined a feature `kind` of type `uima.cas.String`, you can simply write:

```
Doctor.kind=="xyz";

Doctor{Doctor.kind=="xyz"};

d:Doctor{d.kind=="xyz"};

Doctor<-{Person.kind=="xyz";};
```

Some short explanation of the [label expression](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.overview.examples) `d:` and the [inlined rule as condition](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.inlined) (`<-{}`). The label expression introduces a local annotation variable within the scope of the rule. In the above example `d:Doctor` matches on a annotation of the type `Doctor` and assigns it to a new variable called `d`. This variables can then be used in other parts of the rule in order to refer to this specific annotation. In the second rule, no label expression is used and the annotation is refered to by using the type (`Doctor.kind`). Here, the annotation is resolved anew in the context of the match of the rule, which could lead to a different one in case there are several annotations of the type `Doctor`with the same offsets.
The inlined rule as condition works as a complex condition. The rule element `Doctor` matches only if the rule `Person.kind=="xyz";` is able to match within the context/offsets/span of the matched `Doctor` annotation.

Concerning the second part of the question: 
You cannot directly access the annotation which is used in a PARTOF condition because none is used actually. You need to match on the annotation in order to access its features. It depends on which annotation coveres which one, and which annotation should be checked for the feature value. Here are some examples:

```
a:A3{PARTOF(A1),a.x==1};

A1.x=="1"{CONTAINS(A3)};

A1<-{a:A3{a.x=="1"};};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Doctor<-{Person.kind=="xyz";};    does not work as the kind is a feature of Doctor.

It should be Person<-{Doctor.kind=="xyz";};

But this does not match an annotation Person with a child annotation Doctor that has a feature kind with value "xyz".

Comment: [img](https://slack-files.com/T2KSD2BS9-F64LWDFNU-63546b1582) 

In this example we need a rule that would match an annotation of type Card that has a child of type CardType that has a key_CardType with value credit.

Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Also would you be kind enough to provide documentation or a short explanation of    <-    and   :     operators?

Thank you, we Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I extended the answer. I still do not understand your wording concerning child annotations. Are there two annotations? Concerning `Card` and `CardType`: do you mean by child that one is the feautre of the other? Best to create a new question for that so that it can be answered separately.